# Undefined index // php

Tags: php

I'm stuck in my php script for a blog where I want to display the time and date for all the articles. I created a function but I don't know why it doesn't want to work:

```
function articles(){ 
    global $bdd;

    $articles = $bdd->query("SELECT id, titre, accroche, contenu, publication, image FROM articles");
    $articles = $articles->fetchAll();

    return $articles;
}

function formattage_date($publication){ 
    $publication = explode(" ", $publication);
    $date = explode("-", $publication[0]);
    $heure = explode(":", $publication[1]);

    $mois = ["", "janvier", "fevrier", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "decembre"];

    $resultat = $date[2] . ' ' . $mois[$date[1]] . ' ' . $date[0] . ' à ' . $heure[0] . 'h' . $heure[1];

    return $resultat;


}
```

When I want to use `$mois`, php says: `Notice: Undefined index: 03 in C:\wamp\www\entertheletter.dev\fonctions\blog.php on line 18`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the following;

```
$mois[$date[1]]
```

The date string from the database is zerofilled if the value is below 10. So assume that the month is january (janvier), you get `01` instead of `1`. When accessing the `$mois` array with that index, it is not able to find it because `01` is not a valid index.

To fix this, remove the first 0 if the date is zerofilled. Or just cast it to `int` like

```
$mois[(int)$date[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this function where i have added ltrim function in $mois array we have to converted 01 to 0 because array index start from 0,1,2 ...

so we have to remove 0 from 01.

```
 function formattage_date($publication){ 
  $publication = explode(" ", $publication);
  $date = explode("-", $publication[0]);
  $heure = explode(":", $publication[1]);

  $mois = ["", "janvier", "fevrier", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "decembre"];


  $resultat = $date[2] . ' ' . $mois[ltrim($date[1],0)] . ' ' . $date[0] . ' à ' . $heure[0] . 'h' . $heure[1];

return $resultat;


}
```